# Copying project from tortoise svn as is

Tags: tortoisesvn, copy-paste

Is there any way I can just copy my entire project from SVN and paste it to my local hard disk. I don't want to merge my copy and the working copy,I just want to take the working copy as it is? How do you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click in desired location and click "SVN checkout"
2. Paste the url location.
3. Set checkout directory rest remain default.
4. Click ok.

Comment: Do you see "SVN checkout" in context menu on right mouse click ?

Comment: Ok gud, you should click it, a dialog box will open up, enter the "url of repository" the place where the working copy lies then set the "Checkout directory" its a location where you want to save the copy, then click "Ok". A local working copy will be copied from SVN to your hard disk.